# Sql Server Database Backup

Tags: sql-server-2008

How Can I backup An Sql Server Database To My Local Drive From Remote Server

Answer (score 0):

You can run a 'generate script' task from within SSMS that allows you to save it to disk local to where SSMS is running from. It's not a 'SQL Server Backup' in the traditional sense, but it is a backup of data.

If you need a .bak file that's an actual 'backup', you need to save it local to the SQL server and copy it.

Comment: The other alternative is to share a directory from your computer and make sure the SQL Server service account has permission to write to it. Then you can back up to the share directly. (We did this for a while to write backups to a remote server.) But for a quick one-time backup that you need to run, it's probably more trouble than it's worth. Just make a local backup, and move the .bak file to your machine when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it every (hour,day,week) make a dump using the special script (you may find lots of them in the internet) and download the last dump to you local drive.

Another way is to use software specializing in that -  [Handy Backup](http://www.handybackup.net) or [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com), they can backup your DB remotely to wherever you want, I don't know exactly how they backup to local drive, I mean, whether they store in aproprietary format or not, but Handy Backup can store backups online, so you will be able to get dumps via ftp from their servers.